# Problemas en rutas dinámicas con Heroku y PHP MVC

Tags: php, mvc, heroku

Tengo un problema al hacer deploy en heroku: cuando intento acceder a una url a la cual le paso un id como parámetro en la misma url, me sale un error donde dice que la página no ha sido encontrada, ¿por qué?

Este es mi archivo *.htaccess*

```
Options -MultiViews
    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Mi archivo Router

```
public array $getRoutes = [];
    public array $postRoutes = [];

    public function get($url, $fn)
    {
        $this->getRoutes[$url] = $fn;
    }

    public function post($url, $fn)
    {
        $this->postRoutes[$url] = $fn;
    }

    public function comprobarRutas()
    {
        $currentUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '' ? '/' : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        if ($method === 'GET') {
            $fn = $this->getRoutes[$currentUrl] ?? null;
        } else {
            $fn = $this->postRoutes[$currentUrl] ?? null;
        }

        if ($fn) {
            call_user_func($fn, $this);
        } else {
            echo "Página No Encontrada o Ruta no válida";
        }
    }
```

Y esta es la función que se manda llamar cuando entro al enlace

```
public static function Mensaje(Router $router)
    {
        isAuth();

        $id = $_GET['id'];
      
        $userMessage = UserMessage::find($id);

        $router->render('/admin/mensaje', [
            'alertas' => [],
            'enviado' => '',
            'admin' => true,
            'userMessage' => $userMessage
        ]);
    }
```

Todas las rutas funcionan bien hasta que entro a esa ruta en específico, la cual es `admin/mensaje?id=x`: ahí es donde empieza el problema.

Comment: Gracias ya actualicé el post, no suelo hacer uso de stackoverflow así que no sabia cual era la mejor manera de preguntar.

Comment: En cuanto a la mejor manera de preguntar, siempre recomendamos este enlace [ask] para ello. Para aprender la dinámica del sitio este otro enlace: [tour]. Y para poner el código este último enlace: [example]

Comment: Agradezco su respuesta, ya actualicé el post como me recomendaste. Me excuso si vuelvo a cometer algún error, y estaré pendiente si necesitas algo más para poder ayudarme. También revisaré los links adjuntados para tener un mayor control sobre la plataforma, gracias.

Comment: Fue un typo, pero es algo que escribí en el post (haciendo referencia a "admin/mensajes?id=x") ya lo corregí

Comment: Bueno, pues a mi se me acabaron las ideas :-)  Pero tal como tienes ahora la pregunta será más facil que finalmente alguien te responda mejor. Supongo que yo en tu caso empezaría a poner **echo** seguido de **die()** por todas partes para ir siguiendo los valores de las variables o URLs que supuestamente se reciben e interpretan para delimitar el problema hasta encontrarlo. Suerte!

Comment: Agradezco tus respuestas, ya encontré una solución; Al parecer el problema radica en el .htaccess y en el Router, tuve que hacer una reconfiguración, dejaré el código en la parte inferior por si a alguien se le presenta el mismo problema, gracias.

Comment: Perfecto! Sí, ponla, asi la comunidad sabrá que encontrastes la respuesta. En unas 48 horas podrás marcarla como aceptada y así le darás más visibilidad. Gracias por tu aporte y colaboración!

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar esto, solo actualicé el archivo .htaccess y el Router

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Router

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
            $currentUrl = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';
        } else {
            $currentUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '' ? '/' : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }
```